# Issue with splitting a string which includes a dollar sign

Tags: java, split

I am trying to split the following string:

```
addi    $1, $0, 0x1     # $1 = 1
```

on a " " character in Java, like this:

```
String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
```

However, every time I try, I get an exception once the split hits the first dollar sign, as shown:

```
addi    $10, Exception in thread "main"
```

I cannot change the input to not include a dollar sign, so I'm not sure how to fix this error or if there is a different function which would perform better.

```
String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < splitLine.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(splitLine[i]);
}
String inst = splitLine[0];
String[] twoRegs = new String[2]; // used if an instruction uses two registers
twoRegs[0] = splitLine[1];
twoRegs[1] = splitLine[2];
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace because I cannot reproduce the error on my IDE.

Comment: addiException in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Main.cycle(Main.java:60)
 at Main.main(Main.java:39)

Comment: that problem is **not** with the `split() ` method. can you post your full code? the `split()` method  can only `PatternSyntaxException` nothing else.

Comment: Just added it. I assumed it's an issue with split, as it stops after the first split and doesn't have any more entries in the array beside the first "word"

Comment: you'll have to show the full code, both my  `cycle` method and `main`  method. the problem is not within the given code.

Comment: The dollar sign isn't the problem. If your line is explicitly containing tabs, you can't split on a space character

Comment: @cricket_007 i think that was a typo from OP.

Comment: I put all of cycle in there, and main just calls cycle with the given string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting on any whitespace

```
String[] splitLine = line.split("\\s+");
```

Note: the commas are included in these strings. I'm not sure if you want your assembly code to keep commas